# Moment.js: Is it possible to zero pad a time (LT)?

Tags: javascript, date-formatting, momentjs, time-format

We display a column of dates and times, and use Moment.js to format the text that is displayed:

Let's assume that adate is September 9, 2013 and the time is 08:00 AM.

```
var formatted = moment(adate).format("L LT");
```

The date is perfect and is zero padded, for example: 09/22/2013

The time is not zero padded; I am getting 8:00

Is there a way to tell Moment.js to zero pad the time, so my column of dates and times looks good?

I am using version 2.1.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to alter the longDateFormat ([docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/long-date-formats/)): `LT: "hh:mm A"` (the hh is the important bit)

```
moment.lang('en', {
    longDateFormat : {
        LT: "hh:mm A",
        L: "MM/DD/YYYY",
        l: "M/D/YYYY",
        LL: "MMMM Do YYYY",
        ll: "MMM D YYYY",
        LLL: "MMMM Do YYYY LT",
        lll: "MMM D YYYY LT",
        LLLL: "dddd, MMMM Do YYYY LT",
        llll: "ddd, MMM D YYYY LT"
    }
});

var d = moment("Dec 25, 1995 4:00 AM GMT")

d.format("L LT")
```

Result:

```
"12/24/1995 08:00 PM" // I'm GMT -8 so it checks out for me :)
```

I haven't tested to see if you can just set the LT by itself. Seems possible/likely.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!  Since the date format is available in padded and unpadded versions, I assumed that time would handle both, too (i.e. lt for "h:mm A"  and LT for "hh:mm A".  I wonder how we can request this to be added?  Any ideas?  I am sure others would like it, too.  Thank you again for your help! :)

Comment: I think the config system (moment.lang) works fine in that case. No need to add it to the code base.